# In PGFplots, how can I have arrows as markers for plots in order to have them appear in the legend?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In my plot, I want to indicate the direction of a graph with arrows.

Usually, I would just create something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=center,
        xmax=3.5,xmin=-4,
        ymax=6,ymin=-4,
        xlabel=$x_1$,
        ylabel=$x_2$,
        xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty
        ]
    \addplot[smooth,domain=-3.5:2.7,mark=none,black]{-(x/1.5+0.1)^2 + 2};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\arronestart}{-(-0.6/1.5+0.1)^2+2};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\arroneend}{-(-0.59/1.5+0.1)^2+2};
    \draw[
     decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[ultra thick]{stealth}}},
     postaction={decorate}
     ] (axis cs:-0.6,\arronestart) -- (axis cs:-0.59,\arroneend);
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\arrtwostart}{-(2.69/1.5+0.1)^2+2};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\arrtwoend}{-(2.7/1.5+0.1)^2+2};
    \draw[
     decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[ultra thick]{stealth}}},
     postaction={decorate}
     ] (axis cs:2.69,\arrtwostart) -- (axis cs:2.7,\arrtwoend);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now, what I would like to have is a legend entry for those arrows, something like: ->- , but of course this is not possible with \draw[] ;. So, is there a way to have arrows as markings, so that I can create the same graph just using \addplot instead of \draw and have a proper legend?

Comment: Do graphs have directions?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think they don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `\addlegendimage` command to document custom draw statements:

```
        \draw[red,->] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:1,2);
    \addlegendimage{red,->}
    \addlegendentry{Something}
```

Here, the `\addlegendimage` provides the options to visualize the legend entry and `\addlegendentry` provides the text.